# Why is static content request going to uwsgi?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm setting up my Django project to work with uwsgi and nginx.  For static content, I have the following in my nginx.conf:

```
location /static {
    alias /Users/me/mystatic; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
}
```

I have set `STATIC_ROOT` to `/Users/me/mystatic` and called `collectstatic` to copy all the static files into that directory.  In my uwsgi log, I see GET requests for the static content.  Since nginx is supposed to serve the static content, why is the GET request sent to uwsgi?

Comment: try adding /static/ to location

Comment: if it doesn't work out, pls add the rest of the nginx conf, also, make sure that STATIC_URL is "/static/" in your django settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had placed my own nginx.conf in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, not `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers`.  In `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, `include servers/*;` is at the end.  Therefore, UWSGI was still serving the static files.  I followed the [django-nginx-uwsgi tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site), and I assumed I had to create a new `sites-enabled` directory.  I am using OS X.

I see on Linux, though, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has include `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` at the end, so the steps in the tutorial are applicable on Linux.

The extra `/` at the end of `/static` doesn't make a difference, but it doesn't hurt to have it at the end of all paths.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `STATIC_URL` is set as `"/static/"`.

The nginx conf should look something like this:

```
server {

    listen  80 ;
    server_name XXXX;
    client_max_body_size 4G;            

    location /static/ {
        alias <path-to-collectstatic>
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi_web.sock;
    }

}
```

Notice the appending `/` in `location` block for `static`

Last thing, make sure that application server is running with `DEBUG` as `False`

Comment: Yes, I have ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'```.  I'll try ```location /static/``` tonight, but I want to point out that the [nginx-uwsgi-django tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site) uses just ```/static```.